# xcookybooky -- Ingredients and Steps positioning issue

Tags: positioning

I am seeing something odd positioning issue when my recipes flow from end of one page to next. The page screenshot bellow shows the issue. The "Ingredience" in top left is higher than the "Příprava" left of it. When the recipe does not split between two pages (the next recipe starting on the same page) then the position of "Ingredience" is slightly lower than that of "Příprava". Is this intentional or is it a bug in xcookybooky?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: could you confirm that Marco Daniel's link is a duplicate? :)

Comment: @cmhughes: Well, it is from the same document. However I think they are two different issues though.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question to say how they differ- once that is done, we can probably reopen the question.